# Triangulation of L shaped region

Tags: matlab

I want to triangulate the region L = (-1,1)^2 \ [0,1)^2 using the delaunay function, but I can't seem to get it to work.

What I did was simply use meshgrid on the rectangular region of the left side of L:

```
[x_left, y_left] = meshgrid(-1:0.25:0,-1:0.25:1)
```

and on the the square region in the 4th quadrant:

```
[x_right, y_right] = meshgrid(0:0.25:1,-1:0.25:1)
```

Then concatenate the two and call the delaunay function on those two, however, this does not yield the intended result, since I have e.g. a triangle side connecting the points (1,0) and (0,1).

Does anybody know how to triangulate this L-shaped region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `inpolygon` to find triangles centers which contained in the L shape:

```
% generate grid on [-1 1] interval
[xg,yg] = meshgrid(linspace(-1,1));
% coordinates of L corners
x = [-1 0 0 1 1 -1].';
y = [-1 -1 0 0 1 1].';
% generate L binary mask using inpolygon
[IN,ON] = inpolygon(xg,yg,x,y);
bw = IN | ON;
% triangulate L corners
TRI = delaunay(x,y);
% get triangle centers coordinates
c = [mean(x(TRI),2) mean(y(TRI),2)];
% check if centers inside L
IN = inpolygon(c(:,1),c(:,2),x,y);
% remove triangles whose centers outside L
TRI = TRI(IN,:);
% visualize
imshow(bw,'XData',[-1 1],'YData',[-1 1],'InitialMagnification','fit');
hold on;
triplot(TRI,x,y,'LineWidth',2);
```

[image]